# How to get text from textbox in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I run my GAS as an Apps-script-gadget on my web-page and use the GUI-builder. I have two questions:

1.
I know how to set text in a textbox:
    app.getElementById("TextBox1").setText("BigSister");

But how do i get text from a textbox?

I tried:
    app.getElementById("TextBox1").getText();
...getValue();
...value;
etc.

Nothing works...

2.
Is it possible to print a message window from the code to the screen f.Ex. for debugging purposes?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

EDIT here is a workin example for you to test

[online](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw_oqlu46NuqosMD5kUvMNwOJlVr9CAj6ue869E3ZtCjEDzAEM/exec) test

and the [script + GUI is here](https://script.google.com/d/1c0P7oflSTkzDO_V4AUtDIwNGHU5nijawrXo4GZmGokLXP1vLpn4kuqty/edit)

=======================

Srik answer is absolutely right - as usual ;-) - but to make things a bit more clear to you since you are using GUI builder here is a small screen capture that shows the relevant parameters.

[image]

As for your second question, the simplest thing to do to get a momentary showing window to 'print' some data to screen is to use a texBox or a textAreal (or anything else that allows to show text...) and play with the `setVisible(true)` & `setVisible(false)` to show/hide the widget. In the GUI builder you can put it anywhere in your UI, even over other elements that you normally use since it will be invisible most of the time (the visibility parameter is available in the GUI builder environment as well). It will behave exactly as a 'popup' in other environments...

Comment: See my screen capture, maybe it explains better whats my problem. As you can see nowwhere is the text TextBox what the log shows. Where does it come from? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And thanks for the answer to my second question. That was actually the way i was doing it. Just tought maybe it could be easier! ;-)

Comment: Can you clarify where this piece of code you show in the screen capture is ? is it in a handler function or in the `do Get` function ? Also why are you using `jsonStringify` in this context ? From what I see your code should be something like `Logger.log(e.parameter.FieldTwo)` if it is in the handler.  If you need the textValue in the `doGet` function it is easier to set it in the script rather than in the GUI as there are no getText nor getValue methods for textBoxes. The value `TextBox' that you are getting is simply the type of the widget, in this case a TextBox !

Comment: I tried to do like you said, see new screen shot, but it still returns the type of the widget: TextBox. I used the commented //throw for testing that the code really runs in my func2. I use the jsonStringify because its the only way I know how to put text in Logger. Seen it somewhere in the Tutorials. ;-)

Comment: Please insert your screen capture in your question instead. Seeing your code I see you used set name() and thus modified text box name... you should change e.parameter accordingly . Also : try Logger.log(tbox2)

Comment: I added the set.name() because Srik adviced me. I have no idea why this have to be done. Would it be possibble that you write for me a workin code example using my UI. It should just check if the content of TextBox2 is changed and write the result to Logger. I suppose its max about 10 lines of code. Maybe this would be the fastest solution than this where I try to figure out what I should do. ;-)

Comment: I added a screen shot with complete code, GUI-view and empty Logger file. The throw is not commented in the screen shot but in the code itself it is, sorry. This is what I have understand till now. It's not working and I am frustated because this should be so simple but I just can not get it working. Im very thankfull that you have helped me. Maybe the moment comes when I can also read the content of a textbox! ;-DDD Could you please check the screen shot and give me more advice? It would help me a lot.

Comment: function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("Panel1"));
  //I think the next line is unnessecaty but do it still because adviced
  app.getElementById('TextBox1').setName('TextBox1');

  var tbox = app.getElementById('TextBox1');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('func1');
      
  tbox.addValueChangeHandler(handler);
  return app; 
}

function func1(e) { 
  var app2 = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(e.parameter.FieldOne);
  throw "testthrow";
  return app2;
}

Comment: And sorry that its in one piece because I dont know how to make a new line. Enter just sends the comment....

Comment: sorry no time just now, I'll come back later.

Comment: I'm happy if I just get this working. See you later! :-) Btw. Logger.log(tbox) did'nt work neither....

Comment: The online test works fine! But... I copied the code, copied the GUI and run it as a stand alone script (from Drive) and nothing happens.??? The UI is fine but nothing happens after pressing the button. I was wondering how your code handles the button because there is no code for handling the button...

Comment: I managed to edit your code so that it works like your online test: It prints the text 'You have pressed the button...' in the textbox after pressing the button. But the main problem still remains: How to read text from a textbox?

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you Serge insas for your code example and Srik for your "the name is what matters and not the ID"

Comment: In my example the handler was defined in the GUI builder itself, select the button and look at the bottom of the right column, there is a part concerning handlers and callbackelements... but you can do it in the script as well, it's a matter of choice ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Within your handler code, you can access the value of the text box as

```
var value = e.parameter.TextBox1 ;
```

Before doing this you must have run the setName() method on your text box.
    var tetxbox1 = app.createTextBox().setName('TextBox1');

I suggest you run through some of the tutorials at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles where you can find answers to many of your questions.

Comment: I tried to find the solution in tutorials and elsewhere. Your suggestion does not work neither. It returns TextBox. The ID of the button is TextBox1 and the text it contains is TextBox1. Maybe another hint?

Comment: As I said in my comment, the name (set using setName) is what matters and not the ID. If it still doesn't work can you please post more of your code

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the value of your ListBox when it is passed back through a handler.  It's passed in the parameter class under the Id of the ListBox.  The following is a fool-proof method of retrieving that value:

```
function changeHandler(e)
{
  var source = e.parameter['source'];  //source is your Id of the element
  var value = e.parameter[source];  //value is the selected item as ['a' | 'a,b,c']

  //More code here
}
```

I'm still waiting for a solution to retrieve that value without a handler.

Comment: How do you consider this 'answer' related to the question?  Moreover you assumption is not correct if you use a button for example... and it looks more like a question than an answer...